# Movie about a little girl and her mom fighting a cyborg in a post-apocalyptic desert

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember seeing this movie as a kid in the '90s. I think it's a '90s film but could be '80s, and I think the word cyborg is in the title.

The premise as I remember it is a little girl and her mom are being hunted by some robot or cyborg in a post-apocalyptic desert setting. I remember scenes of them hiding underground and shooting or being shot at by the robot with guns and missiles.

Think *Predator* but with fewer characters and a cyborg in the desert.

Comment: Could you clarify roughly how old the "little girl" is in this movie? Is she a baby, pre-teen, teenager, etc?

Comment: Clearly, this is a reference to Terminator 2: Judgment Day.

Comment: @EricHauenstein I thought the same thing at first, but T2 does not have a little girl

Comment: i remember the girl being young, like pre-teen. I'm not sure the accepted answer of Nemesis 2 is right.

Comment: @nanogoats - I watched some of _Nemesis 2_ while searching for your film. If it helps, I can tell you that the mother arrives in Africa with her baby daughter at the start of the film, and is shot and killed by a human male within the first ten minutes. The film then jumps forward in time over a decade, and the baby has been raised by a local tribe and grown into a young woman (late teens/early twenties) with braided, blonde hair and the physique of a female bodybuilder. The cyborg finally shows up some time later, and pursues the young woman, who is portrayed as a capable warrior.

Answer (score 11):

I've never seen it myself but the 1995 straight-to-video movie [*Nemesis 2: Nebula*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113948/?ref_=m_ttpl) seems close to what you're looking for.  Quoting the [plot summary on Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemesis_2:_Nebula):

> 73 years after Alex failed, **humans have lost the Cyborg Wars** and they are now slaves to the cyborg masters. Rebel scientists have developed a new DNA strain which could signal the end of the cyborgs, and it is injected it into a pregnant volunteer.
>
> When the cyborgs learn of **the woman and her baby,** both are listed for termination. To escape, she steals a cyborg ship and is transported back in time to East Africa in 1980, where the mother is killed but the baby is saved. It takes 20 years, but a cyborg bounty hunter named Nebula eventually locates the young woman, named Alex, and travels back in time to terminate her.

Per Wikipedia, the movie was apparently shot in Globe, Arizona, so most of the sets were desert.  One of the reviews on IMDb describes it as "*Terminator* meets *Predator*."

Comment: this definitely fits my description really well but I doesn't look right to me. I remember the girl being younger, like pre-teen. But hey maybe my memory is really off. I do remember cornrows or dreadlocks so that sorta fits...

Comment: ok on further consideration i think this or Nemesis 3 is the one!

Answer (score 1):

According to a comment from the OP above, this film is [Nemesis 3: Time Lapse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nemesis_3:_Prey_Harder). The movie begins with Alex waking up in the desert. According to [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113950/):

> Alex again fighting the cyborg mercenaries in 1998 East Africa. This
> time, Alex finds that she has 20 half sisters who are waiting for her
> to return to 2077. Central Command wants Alex captured alive and
> scanned to see if her DNA is a strong and more powerful strain than
> the normal. But Alex may be too tough for Farnsworth to capture.

Comment: Does it have a little girl an a woman/mother?  Can you add a bit more information about how this fits?

Comment: @Raj - The OP also mentioned a pre-teen girl, and there isn't one in this from the bits of it I've looked at. There doesn't seem to be a mother character either, just the young woman from the previous film. _Nebula 2_ was a closer match, since there was actually a mother and daughter in that one, but even there the mother died long before the cyborg actually showed up, and we never saw the daughter as a pre-teen, only as a baby and a young woman.